# ChartJS - Show values in the center of each bar

Tags: javascript, chart.js

See image below, I'm trying to set the value of each bar in the center of my stacked bar; so far I only got on the top and sometimes the position is off (see the 4% yellow in the third bar)

This is the code:

```
context.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
    for (var i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++) {
        var model = dataset._meta[Object.keys(dataset._meta)[0]].data[i]._model,
            scale_max = dataset._meta[Object.keys(dataset._meta)[0]].data[i]._yScale.maxHeight;
        var textY = model.y + 50;
        if ((scale_max - model.y) / scale_max >= 0.5)
            textY = model.y + 20;
        fadeIn(ctx, dataset.data[i], model.x, textY, model.y > topThreshold, step);
    }
});

var fadeIn = function(ctx, obj, x, y, black, step) {
    var ctx = modifyCtx(ctx);
    var alpha = 0;
    ctx.fillStyle = black ? 'rgba(' + outsideFontColor + ',' + step + ')' : 'rgba(' + insideFontColor + ',' + step + ')';
    ctx.fillText(obj.toString() + "%", x, y);
};
```

[image]

Comment: You want to place the texts in the center of the whole bars (i.e. almost like the 2nd bar) *or* the center of its specific bar (i.e. almost like yellow and red of the 4th bar)?

Comment: @adelriosantiago I want to place the texts in the center of each specific bar(color); yes, the 4th bar looks like almost what I want

Comment: Could you add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I have tried several times but I am not able to use the function you posted above. You can use [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adelriosantiago/fxge4wcr/16/) as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with the [Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api). The API offers different hooks that may be used for executing custom code (that's probably what you already do). In your case, you can use the `afterDraw` hook as follows to draw text at the desired positions.

```
afterDraw: chart => {
  let ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
  ctx.save();
  ctx.textAlign = 'center';
  ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
  ctx.font = "12px Arial";
  let xAxis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
  let yAxis = chart.scales['y-axis-0'];
  let datasets = chart.chart.data.datasets.filter(ds => !ds._meta[0].hidden);
  xAxis.ticks.forEach((value, xIndex) => {
    let x = xAxis.getPixelForTick(xIndex);
    datasets.forEach((dataset, iDataset) => {
      if (dataset.data[xIndex] > 3) {
        let yValue = datasets.slice(0, iDataset)
          .map(ds => ds.data[xIndex])
          .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) +
          dataset.data[xIndex] / 2;
        let y = yAxis.getPixelForValue(yValue);
        ctx.fillStyle = dataset.textColor;
        ctx.fillText(dataset.data[xIndex] + '%', x, y);
      }
    });
  });
  ctx.restore();
}
```

Please take a look at below runnable code and see how it works.

```js
const chart = new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'bar',
  plugins: [{
    afterDraw: chart => {
      let ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
      ctx.save();
      ctx.textAlign = 'center';
      ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
      ctx.font = "12px Arial";
      let xAxis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
      let yAxis = chart.scales['y-axis-0'];
      let datasets = chart.chart.data.datasets.filter(ds => !ds._meta[0].hidden);
      xAxis.ticks.forEach((value, xIndex) => {
        let x = xAxis.getPixelForTick(xIndex);
        datasets.forEach((dataset, iDataset) => {
          if (dataset.data[xIndex] > 3) {
            let yValue = datasets.slice(0, iDataset)
              .map(ds => ds.data[xIndex])
              .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) +
              dataset.data[xIndex] / 2;
            let y = yAxis.getPixelForValue(yValue);
            ctx.fillStyle = dataset.textColor;
            ctx.fillText(dataset.data[xIndex] + '%', x, y);
          }
        });
      });
      ctx.restore();
    }
  }],
  data: {
    labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Dataset 1',
      data: [2.5, 48, 9, 17, 23],
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      textColor: 'white'
    }, {
      label: 'Dataset 2',
      data: [2.5, 4, 4, 11, 11],
      backgroundColor: 'orange',
      textColor: 'black'
    }, {
      label: 'Dataset 3',
      data: [95, 48, 87, 72, 66],
      backgroundColor: 'green',
      textColor: 'white'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="160"></canvas>
```